# Как работает null в Java?

Tags: java, объекты, null

Расскажите, почему при вызове строчки `m(null)` в консоль выводится "String", получается `null` является `String` - объектом?

```java
public class Main {
    static void m(Object i) {
        System.out.print("Object");
    }

    static void m(String i) {
        System.out.print("String");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object i = null;
        m(i);
        m(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение `null` имеет тип интерфейса [`javax.lang.model.type.NullType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/NullType.html). Этот тип расширяет [`ReferenceType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/ReferenceType.html) и может быть использован для любых ссылок. При выборе перегруженной функции [компилятор отдает предпочтение варианту, использующему наиболее *частный* тип](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). А так как `String` является подтипом `Object`, то тут вызывается вариант функции, принимающий ссылку на `String`.

Можно привести пример посложнее. Здесь `Number` будет предпочтительней `Object`, а `Integer` предпочтительей `Number`:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void test(Object str) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void test(Number str) {
        System.out.println("Number");
    }

    public static void test(Integer str) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(null);
    }
}
```